# Why is this answer wrong? (rational expressions)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Simplify the following expression:

$$q=\frac { z+9 }{ 5 } +10$$

this is what I got:

$$q=\frac { z+9 }{ 5 } +\frac { 50 }{ 5 } $$
$$ q=\frac { z+9+50 }{ 5 } $$

This answer is wrong:
$$q=\frac { z+59 }{ 5 } $$

Comment: $\frac{z}{5}+11\frac{4}{5}$

Comment: It's algebraically correct. The only ambiguity is what they mean by "simplify". They might expect an answer like $q = \frac 15 (z+59)$ or even $q = \frac 15 z + 11\frac 45$. Frankly, I would consider marking you wrong to be extreme nitpicking.

Comment: All the steps are correct; the "answer" however depends on what the instructor believes "simplified" means.

Comment: $\frac{z}{5}+11+\frac{4}{5}$ OR $\frac{z+4}{5}+11$, different ways of expressing same quantity

Comment: Whoever asks you the question should *absolutely* be required to tell you what form the answer should have. There is no single "simplification", the term is very application specific. Heck, in many engineering scenarios I know of, grade school style "simplifications" are actually counterproductive. So you should bash your instructor, deservedly so. It's this sort of ambiguity and smugness of instructors that should be vanquished at all costs. It's not conducive to learning. Using the term "wrong answer" here is **very unprofessional**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$q=\frac{z+9}{5}+\frac{50}{5}=\frac{z+9+50}{5}=\frac{z+59}{5}$$

It is correct..

Comment: I'm being told that it is incorrect. Supposedly it can be further simplified?

Comment: Did your prof tell you that it isn't right? If so,did he tell you what else you should  have done?

Comment: This was a problem on https://www.khanacademy.org

I entered the answer I got and it said it was wrong. And that it could have been simplified further.

Comment: @Cherry_Developer I will take a look at the exercise..Have you found it at the subject "Precalculus" ?